# Roslyn Analyzer + Code Fix - Replacing Node with Descendant Node

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I've written an analyzer that will flag certain methods if they're not marked as `async`.

I'm now implementing a code fixer that will make them async.

It'll also either add an await expression, or it'll remove a `Task.FromResult` call and just return the object directly.

To do the latter, I'm doing this:

```cs
var expressionSyntax = returnStatement.ChildNodes().OfType<ExpressionSyntax>().First()!;

var firstInnerExpression = expressionSyntax.ChildNodes().OfType<ArgumentListSyntax>().First().Arguments.First().Expression;

var newReturnStatement = returnStatement.ReplaceNode(expressionSyntax, firstInnerExpression);
                
newMethodDeclarationSyntax = newMethodDeclarationSyntax.ReplaceNode(returnStatement, newReturnStatement);
```

In the debugger, I can see my old return statement is:

`ReturnStatementSyntax ReturnStatement return Task.FromResult<string?>("Foo!");`

My new return statement is:

`ReturnStatementSyntax ReturnStatement return "Foo!";`

However when I call the `method.ReplaceNode`, it doesn't error, but it also doesn't update to the new return statement.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: I remember having this problem when I wrote an analyzer a year ago or something. You are most likely running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41044506/547640. TLDR; The syntax-tree has changed and the original node you want to replace isn't available anymore so you need to find it again (or build a new return statement instead of modifying the existing one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you make several node replacements in your code. Just in the snippet there are already two calls to the `SyntaxNode.ReplaceNode` method.

Public data structures in Roslyn are immutable. Similar to strings when you modify a syntax tree with node replacement you will receive a new node which have a new different `SyntaxTree`. If you have some syntax nodes found before the first replacement, then these nodes are part of the old syntax tree.

To make this more obvious I usually call replace on the root node and store the result in a new variable like this:

```cs
    var newRoot = oldRoot.ReplaceNode(oldNode, newGeneratedNode);
```

Attempting to combine nodes with different syntax trees won't be successful. With the second call to `ReplaceNode` one of the nodes just won't be found in the syntax tree of another. No nodes found to replace, no error, everything is OK from the API point of view.

There are several approaches to this issue. I usually use the following two:

1. The most simple approach is to attempt to reduce your calls to `ReplaceNode` to just one. Prepare the new node as much as you can, add everything needed there. Maybe replace not the node you were originally going to replace, but it's ancestor.
2. The previous approach frequently is enough but sometimes you have to call `ReplaceNode` several times. In this case I usually use the `TrackNodes` functionality. The idea is that you can find some nodes before any modifications, explicitly tell Roslyn to mark them, so they could be found in new modified syntax trees. Here is a simple example:

```cs
SyntaxNode someNode, anotherNode; //assume that you have two nodes to modify

//This is also a modification, the trackingRoot has different syntax tree
var trackingRoot = root.TrackNodes(someNode, anotherNode); 
var someNode = trackingRoot.GetCurrentNode(someNode); // node has to be found in the new syntax tree 

if (someNode != null)
{
   var newSomeNode = Modify(someNode);
   trackingRoot = trackingRoot.ReplaceNode(someNode, newSomeNode);
}

var anotherNode= trackingRoot.GetCurrentNode(anotherNode); // node has to be found in the new syntax tree 

if (anotherNode!= null)
{
   var newAnotherNode = Modify(anotherNode);
   trackingRoot = trackingRoot.ReplaceNode(anotherNode, newAnotherNode);
}
```

You can find an example of such code fix in the open source project I maintain:
https://github.com/Acumatica/Acuminator/blob/dev/src/Acuminator/Acuminator.Analyzers/StaticAnalysis/NonPublicExtensions/NonPublicExtensionFix.cs#L66-L74

For cases of many edits there are more complex APIs like `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` or `DocumentEditor`. Describing them all will make this answer huge. If you are interested here is a link to good series of blog posts describing them:
https://joshvarty.com/2015/08/18/learn-roslyn-now-part-12-the-documenteditor/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! In the end, I ended up using `DocumentEditor`, which I found massively easier!? It's so much simpler to use IMO and you don't have to deal with the complexity of immutability!

Comment: @TomH, my pleasure, I've mentioned `DocumentEditor` in the end. I remember now that I've seen an approach that parsed the prepared text to create a syntax node for the replacement.

Still, I believe that for simple code fixes with one replacement it is better to work directly with syntax nodes. It's not that hard, you don't need to do all this node tracking, and I think it will be more performant since other APIs are mostly wrapping syntax nodes.

Comment: @TomH, one can pick `SyntaxGenerator` API to create language agnostic code fixes that work both with C# and VB.Net. But VB code is pretty rare today. So, for me this is not the scenario I usually need to cover. And F# has significantly different language paradigm, so I think it will require a separate code fix anyway. Also it does not really matter since F# is not supported by Roslyn AFAIK.

Comment: One advantage of the direct syntax nodes manipulation that I found useful is the ability to customize node trivia. You can make custom indentation, formatting, add comments, regions. It is useful for my code fixes.

Comment: @TomH if you found the answer useful please select is as the answer to your question.